# Error reading manifest file "...datanucleus-core-3.0.0-release.jar!/plugin.xml"

Tags: netbeans, import, jdo, datanucleus

I got a very strange error. This what I've done:

I create a project (with Netbeans) which include datanucleuse-core-3.0.0-release.jar. The project can be built successfully. It also ran smoothly when I tried to run it with Netbeans or running 'java -jar <.jar bundle>' in dist folder via command prompt.

The problem is, when I copy that dist folder into another location and tried to run it again with command prompt, it gave these errors:

> Exception in thread "main" Error reading manifest file
>   "jar:file:/E:/!new/BTJ/NCRServer/lib/datanucleus-core-3.0.0-release.jar!/plugin.xml"
>   org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Error reading manifest
>   file "jar:fi
>   le:/E:/!new/BTJ/NCRServer/lib/datanucleus-core-3.0.0-release.jar!/plugin.xml"
>           at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerBundle(NonMan
>   agedPluginRegistry.java:481)
>           at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerExtensions(No
>   nManagedPluginRegistry.java:219)
>           at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerExtensionPoin
>   ts(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:160)
>           at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.(PluginManager.java:62)
>           at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.(NucleusContext.java:211)
>           at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.(NucleusContext.java:166)
>           at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.(JDOPersis
>   tenceManagerFactory.java:360)
>           at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenc
>   eManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:290)
>           at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceMa
>   nagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:191)
>           at com.ncr.server.Server.(Server.java:68)
>           at com.ncr.server.Server.main(Server.java:91) Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\ (The system cannot find the path s
>   pecified)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:114)
>           at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:135)
>           at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:99)
>           at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerBundle(NonMan
>   agedPluginRegistry.java:390)
>           ... 10 more Nested Throwables StackTrace: java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\ (The system cannot find the path
>   specified)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
>           at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:114)
>           at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:135)
>           at java.util.jar.JarFile.(JarFile.java:99)
>           at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerBundle(NonMan
>   agedPluginRegistry.java:390)
>           at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerExtensions(No
>   nManagedPluginRegistry.java:219)
>           at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerExtensionPoin
>   ts(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:160)
>           at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.(PluginManager.java:62)
>           at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.(NucleusContext.java:211)
>           at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.(NucleusContext.java:166)
>           at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.(JDOPersis
>   tenceManagerFactory.java:360)
>           at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenc
>   eManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:290)
>           at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceMa
>   nagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:191)
>           at com.ncr.server.Server.(Server.java:68)
>           at com.ncr.server.Server.main(Server.java:91)

Anybody got clue ?

Answer (score 0):

I am really sorry for everyone, especially for datanucleus members in StackOverflow.

Apparently the problem is me, not the netbeans, datanucleus API, nor anyone.
As you can see from "jar:file:/E:/!new/BTJ/NCRServer/lib/datanucleus-core-3.0.0-release.jar!/plugin.xml", I put the "dist" folder from Netbeans in "E:/!new" folder. I don't know why but the "!new" folder seems to cause the extra exclamation mark(!) in "release.jar!".

I move the dist folder into D:/ and it worked !!

So, if anyone ever experience this problem (precedence a folder's name with exclamation mark and accidentally put a project with datanucleus-core-3.0.0-release.jar inside it), that's the solution.

Thank you.